# Store on Windows

Tags: pnpm

I don't know if this is a bug or a lack of understanding. I don't get how the pnpm store works on Windows.

Say, I use a folder "test" on C: - the store (.pnpm-store) is created in %USERPROFILE%. When I have this folder "test" on another drive, the store is created inside "test". Furthermore, when there would be another folder "test2" on this very drive, another new store will be created in "test2". IMO, "test" and "test2" on this (other - not c) drive should use a store in the root of this drive (yes, my user can create a folder there), shouldn't it.

Then, let's suppose I have a folder "test", with a package folder inside called "package1" and I create package.json by "pnpm init -y". Now I add a package, eg "pnpm add debug". IMO the store on this drive should be referenced. But it isn't:

```
C:\test\package1>dir /s | findstr JUNCTION
10.10.2019  13:25    <JUNCTION>     debug [C:\test\package1\node_modules\.pnpm\registry.npmjs.org\debug\4.1.1\node_modules\debug]
10.10.2019  13:25    <JUNCTION>     ms [C:\test\package1\node_modules\.pnpm\registry.npmjs.org\ms\2.1.2\node_modules\ms]
10.10.2019  13:25    <JUNCTION>     ms [C:\test\package1\node_modules\.pnpm\registry.npmjs.org\ms\2.1.2\node_modules\ms]
```

So what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> drive should use a store in the root of this drive (yes, my user can create a folder there), shouldn't it.

When you install on the same drive where the users dir is, the store is created in users dir. When you install on other drives, the store is created at the root of the drive (for instance, at `D:\.pnpm-store`)

> the store on this drive should be referenced. But it isn't

That package that you see in your project is physically the same package as the one in the store. It is a hard link. More details from the [pnpm FAQ page](https://pnpm.js.org/en/faq):

> pnpm creates hard links from the global store to project's
>   node_modules folders. Hard links point to the same place on the disk
>   where the original files are. So, for example, if you have foo in your
>   project as a dependency and it occupies 1MB of space, then it will
>   look like it occupies 1MB of space in the project's node_modules
>   folder and the same amount of space in the global store. However, that
>   1MB is the same space on the disk addressed from two different
>   locations. So in total foo occupies 1MB, not 2MB.

Comment: Thank you - I had read the FAQ ;-) But apparently it doesn't work like this on Windows.

Comment: It should now work as expected in the latest version of pnpm (v4.1.4)